# Python - define custom exception class

Tags: python, exception

I want to declare a custom exception class such that whenever it is raised it will do a specific set of actions. I would be raising this exception at multiple places so don't want to add an except block at all these places. Instead I prefer to override the function which would raise the error.

Suppose I have a class -

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass
```

I do this -

```
raise CustomException(**kwargs)
```

I wish to extract data from the kwargs and do some action depending on them.